# An army marches

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This is my first riddle - I think it is probably quite an easy one. I'm interested to see how quickly it gets solved. There is an overall theme with four elements to be identified.

> The Red Army marches
>   All throughout the land
>   Distributing their supplies
>   So that their lord may stand
>
> The Officers are dressed in white
>   And keep a watchful eye
>   They are prepared to fight
>   All foreign threats which fly
>
> The Medics join in the march
>   Although smaller than the rest
>   They group around the injured
>   And heal them their best
>
> The Canals aid all their passage
>   Delivering them with haste
>   Bringing a balance to the land
>   And washing away the waste

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the red army

> are the red blood cells and the supplies they distribute are oxygen

The white army

> are the white blood cells which produce antibodies and protect against disease

The Medics

> are platelets as suggested by tmpearce, which rush to areas of injury form a clot.

The canals

> are plasma, which transport the blood cells and other nutrients.  (Thanks again to tmpearce).  The blood vessels, provide the infrastructure, but aren't part of the answer after all!

Comment: The Medics might be cyngryrgf, tebhcvat bagb vawherq irffryf naq sbezvat pybgf

Comment: Awesome work and very fast! The last two features I had a slightly different intended answer - @tmpearce correctly picked out the one I had in mind for the Medics. I admit the "canals" can be a bit ambiguous but given rot13(gurer vf n ernfba sbe rknpgyl sbhe ryrzragf) that might help narrow down what I was aiming at.

Comment: While I think the word "canals" is most compatible with the physical structure interpretation you came up with, in light of the comment above you might consider cynfzn, gur aba-pryyhyne sbhegu znwbe pbzcbarag bs oybbq. Perhaps the last stanza would be better phrased as "The Navy provides them passage..." or something like that

Comment: Yes @tmpearce - that is what I had in mind. Gur znva wbo bs cynfzn vf gb genafcbeg gur gur oybbq pryyf naq bgure ahgevragf / jnfgr. Nyfb vg urycf znvagnva gur obql'f syhvq "onynapr" nf uvagrq gb va gur irefr. But I think one does immediately think of the physical structure first - I'll mark this answer as correct as it pretty much nails it otherwise. :)

Comment: @Johnson I agree, I think lines 2-4 of the stanza fit very well, just not the word "canals" :)

Comment: Noice, this reminds me of an anime, rot13(Pryyf ng Jbex!) :)

Comment: and here i was hoping the answer was going to be about ants